# Aptana Studio 3.0.7.201112021709 very slow when saving local files over SAMBA link

Tags: php, aptana

Every time I save a file in Aptana, I get the round busy indicator and have to wait approximately 3-5 seconds.  I have a project on a SAMBA share mapped to local drive (in this case W:).

If I open a remote file via ftp and save it, the save happens reasonably quickly (accounting for the ftp communication overhead).

One thing I noticed was the log file is full of the following entry:

```
!ENTRY com.aptana.git.core 4 0 2011-12-08 15:57:44.980
!MESSAGE (Build 3.0.0.1321991271) [ERROR]  

!ENTRY com.aptana.git.core 4 0 2011-12-08 15:58:12.251
!MESSAGE (Build 3.0.0.1321991271) [ERROR]  

!ENTRY com.aptana.git.core 4 0 2011-12-08 15:58:39.053
!MESSAGE (Build 3.0.0.1321991271) [ERROR]
```

It appears that 3-4 per minute are being logged.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it's over samba, then it isn't local file.

Answer (score 0):

I too have the same issue. I have a `SSH` share via `MacFusion` and `OSXfusion` that has the same issues with very long file saves.

Maybe be a better place is [here](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/)...

hope this helps!